# Prevent the uncompilable part of source code(on per class or package basis) from being compiled

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

Is there a way I could prevent certain classes / packages in my netbeans based maven project from being compiled(by hiding/ ignoring etc) while build as they contain uncompilable code ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your source under different source root (Netbeans supports multiple source roots) and when source is not necessary just remove additional source tree (somewhere in Netbeans project properties)